# Divergence of $\lim_{N\to +\infty}[ \int_{1}^{N+1} f(x) dx -\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(n)] $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, summation

Divergence of  $\lim_{N\to +\infty}[ \int_{1}^{N+1} f(x) dx -\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(n)] $ where $f(x)= sin(log_e x)(\frac{1}{x^{a}}-\frac{1}{x^{1-a}})$,$ 0<a<1/2$

**My try** -
$\lim_{N\to +\infty}[ \int_{1}^{N+1} sin(log_e x)(\frac{1}{x^{a}}-\frac{1}{x^{1-a}})dx - \sum_{n=1}^{N} sin ( log _en) (\frac{1}{n^{a}}-\frac{1}{n^{1-a}})]  $ where $0<a<1/2$

Define S=$\lim_{N\to +\infty}[ \int_{1}^{N+1} sin(log_e x)(\frac{1}{x^{a}}-\frac{1}{x^{1-a}})dx - \sum_{n=1}^{N} sin ( log _en) (\frac{1}{n^{a}}-\frac{1}{n^{1-a}})]  $

If $a=1/2$ then S is convergent to 0.

If $a<1/2$ then, $(\frac{1}{x^{a}}-\frac{1}{x^{1-a}})>0$ $ \forall x\geq 1$
and $(\frac{1}{n^{a}}-\frac{1}{n^{1-a}})>0$ $ \forall n\geq 1$.

Please prove that S is divergent when $0<a<1/2$

Comment: Let $0 < a < 1$ and $g(x) = x^{-a + i}$. You need to show that the limit of $R = \int_1^{N + 1} g(x) dx - \sum_{x = 1}^N g(x)$ exists. The Euler-Maclaurin formula gives
$$R = \frac {g(N + 1) - g(1)} 2 -
\int_1^{N + 1} g'(x) \left( \{ x \} - \frac 1 2 \right) dx.$$
$\int_1^\infty g'(x) (\{ x \} - 1/2) dx$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @Maxim A very nice approach - a real shortcut to the solution. I fact, no need for dumb calculations.

Answer (score 1):

1. Integral $I(a)=\int_{1}^{N+1} \sin(\ln x)(\frac{1}{x^{a}}-\frac{1}{x^{1-a}})dx$  can be evaluated - just make a change $x=e^t$:
   $I(a)=\int_{0}^{\ln(N+1)} \sin(t)(e^{-ta}-e^{(a-1)t})e^tdt=\int_{0}^{\ln(N+1)} \sin(t)(e^{t(1-a)}-e^{at})dt$  and $\sin(t)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}= \Im({e}^{it})$

Integral with exponents can be easily taken.

2. Consider the integral as a sum:  $\sum_{k=1}^{N}\int_{\ln(k)}^{\ln(k+1)} \sin(t)(e^{t(1-a)}-e^{at})dt$

So, you get a series with N term as $a_N=\left(\int_{\ln(N)}^{\ln(N+1)} \sin(t)(e^{t(1-a)}-e^{at})dt-\sin(\ln{N})(\frac{1}{N^{a}}-\frac{1}{N^{1-a}})\right)$ and you can investigate its behaviour at $N\to\infty$.

Let's consider $a_N$:

After evaluating the integral we get:

$a_N=\frac{1-a}{1+(1-a)^2}[(N+1)^{1-a}\sin(\ln(N+1))-N^{1-a}\sin(\ln(N))]-\frac{1}{1+(1-a)^2}[(N+1)^{1-a}\cos(\ln(N+1))-N^{1-a}\cos(\ln(N))]-\frac{a}{1+a^2}[(N+1)^{a}\sin(\ln(N+1))-N^{a}\sin(\ln(N))]+\frac{1}{1+a^2}[(N+1)^{a}\cos(\ln(N+1))-N^{a}\cos(\ln(N))]-[\sin(\ln{N})\frac{1}{N^{a}}]+[\sin(\ln{N})\frac{1}{N^{1-a}}]$

Now, let's consider, for example
$\frac{a}{1+a^2}[(N+1)^{a}\sin(\ln(N+1))-N^{a}\sin(\ln(N))]=\frac{a}{1+a^2}[N^a(1+\frac{1}{N})^{a}\sin(\ln{N}+\ln(1+\frac{1}{N}))-N^{a}\sin(\ln(N))]$

Expanding the sine of the sum, as well as using Taylor series expansion for large N we get

$\frac{aN^a}{1+a^2}[(1+\frac{a}{N}+O(\frac{1}{N^2}))\left(\sin(\ln{N})\cos((\frac{1}{N})+O(\frac{1}{N^2}))+\cos(\ln{N})\sin((\frac{1}{N})+O(\frac{1}{N^2}))\right)-\sin(\ln(N))]=\frac{aN^a}{1+a^2}[(1+\frac{a}{N}+O(\frac{1}{N^2}))\left(\sin(\ln{N})\cos(\frac{1}{N})+O(\frac{1}{N^2})+\cos(\ln{N})\sin(\frac{1}{N})+O(\frac{1}{N^2})\right)-\sin(\ln(N))]=\frac{a}{1+a^2}N^a\left(\frac{a\sin(\ln{N})}{N}+\frac{\cos(\ln{N})}{N}+O(\frac{1}{N^2})\right)$

Finally, evaluating all terms we get

$a_N=N^{-a}\left(\frac{(1-a)^2\sin(\ln{N})}{1+(1-a)^2}+\frac{(1-a)\cos(\ln{N})}{1+(1-a)^2}-\frac{(1-a)\cos(\ln{N})}{1+(1-a)^2}+\frac{\sin(\ln{N})}{1+(1-a)^2}+O(\frac{1}{N^2})\right)+N^{a-1}\left(-\frac{a^2\sin(\ln{N})}{1+a^2}-\frac{a\cos(\ln{N})}{1+a^2}+\frac{a\cos(\ln{N})}{1+a^2}-\frac{\sin(\ln{N})}{1+a^2}+O(\frac{1}{N^2})\right)-$$-\sin(\ln{N})\frac{1}{N^{a}}+\sin(\ln{N})\frac{1}{N^{1-a}}$

After grouping all terms we see that they cancel each other, so we get

$a_N=N^{a}O(\frac{1}{N^2})+N^{1-a}O(\frac{1}{N^2})=O(\frac{1}{N^{2-a}})+O(\frac{1}{N^{1+a}})$

But these series converges absolutely $\Rightarrow$ $a_N$ converges.

Please check my calculations.

Comment: Can you please explain that how you get the integral as a sum in 2?

Comment: $\int_{\ln(1)}^{\ln(N+1)}=\int_{\ln(1)}^{\ln(2)}+\int_{\ln(2)}^{\ln(3)}+...\int_{\ln(N)}^{\ln(N+1)}$

Comment: @Svuatoslav So how can we manipulate $\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(n)$? You have only manipulated I(a). What about the sum?

Comment: I got it. But how $\lim_{N \to +\infty} a_N$ diverges?

Comment: Please reply. I will give you a check mark.

Comment: Yes, the sum$\sum{a}_N$ is probably diverging. The possible way of investigation is to take the integral $\int_{\ln(N)}^{\ln(N+1)} \sin(t)(e^{t(1-a)}-e^{at})dt$ explicitly and then evaluate $a_N=\left(\int_{\ln(N)}^{\ln(N+1)} \sin(t)(e^{t(1-a)}-e^{at})dt-\sin(\ln{N})(\frac{1}{N^{a}}-\frac{1}{N^{1-a}})\right)$

Comment: Please prove that the sum is divergent. I tried but could not do it.

Comment: Ok then please give me some hint to do it.

Comment: I may suppose that $\int_{\ln(N)}^{\ln(N+1)} \sin(t)(e^{t(1-a)}-e^{at})dt$ - after you evaluate it - will look like $\sin(\ln{N})(\frac{1}{N^{a}}-\frac{1}{N^{1-a}})$ but will have some multiplier, so the difference of these terms will behave like $\frac{1}{N^{a}}$, so |$a_N$| might look like $\sim\frac{1}{N^{a}}$ (or like $\sim\frac{1}{N^{1-a}}$, or like the combination of both options) and the sum, therefore, diverges as $N^{1-a}$ or $N^{a}$ (or like their combination). You should take the integral and have a closer look.

Comment: So now you are saying that the limit converges??

Comment: I will wait till evening for your solution. Please do remember to post it.

Comment: Its evening . Please answer.